# setOnItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, onclick

I am not able get onItemCickListener to work.  All I am doing is opening up a fragment using intents.  Please do let me know if I am doing anything fishy here ?

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ArrayList<String> myList = null;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            Log.d("Example:", "In Fragement Calss");
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            Resources myResources = getResources();
            myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(myResources.getStringArray(R.array.myExamArray)));
            myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myList);
            setListAdapter(myAdapter);

            ListView lv = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailsFragment.class);

                startActivity(myIntent);
            }

           });

        }

}
```

Comment: actually I am new to this .. and don't know how the system here works.   I will go ahead and accept the responses.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the ListView blocks clicks of an item that contains at least one focusable
descendant but it doesn’t make the content focus-reachable calling
setItemsCanFocus(true). One workaround is by disabling focusability of descendants, using

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in the layout defining your list item. (First learned of this myself from http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/, but a few other SO posts also point this out.) Does your layout contain buttons? If so, you'd fall into this case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are inflating a specific XML for this Fragment... but it is possible you are referencing the wrong ListView.

Regardless you should use the existing [`onListItemClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) method:

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ArrayList<String> myList = null;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // Remove the OnItemClickListener, but keep everything else
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, DetailsFragment.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Replacing this line of code 
    ListView lv = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView); 

with

    ListView lv = getListView();

triggered the event and was able to invoke my other activity as this fragment was extending listfragment.

Comment: I though that might work, but to me it still makes more sense to use the `onListItemClick` callback than create a _second_ listener by using `setOnItemClickListener()`.